# OpenCV C++ memory leak when passing Mat to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am trying to pass an OpenCV Mat from an image capture thread to an image processing thread as a part of a large application. I have no requirement for the image capture thread and the image processing thread to access the Mat at the same time. As a result, I simply want to pass ownership of the Mat from the image capture thread to the image processing thread. I am using OpenCV 3.

The problem I am encountering is that my program leaks a large amount of memory.

Below I have attached a minimal example of the code I am using to pass the Mats between threads. When I run this code it finishes using somewhere between 10MB and 500MB of memory from just 300 images with a resolution of 1640x1232.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIM_PROCESSING_TIME_MS 150

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

static volatile int keepRunning = 1;
static volatile int runThread = 1;

// Acts as a stack where the last image to be added is the first to be processed.
// If the 'capture' rate is higher than the processing rate then some images are skipped and processed at the end once the 'capture' has stopped.
vector<Mat> unprocessedImages;
mutex unprocessedImageMutex;

void intHandler(int dummy)
{
    keepRunning = 0;
}

// Simulates a function which captures an image using opencv.
Mat GetImage()
{
    return imread("../0000.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
}

// Simulates an image processing thread.
// A delay has been used to replace any actual image processing as in my testing it didn't seem to make a difference.
void image_processing_thread()
{
    int count = 0;
    while(true)
    {

        Mat imageToProcess;

        {// lock the vector and remove the last element
            lock_guard<mutex> lk(unprocessedImageMutex);
            if (unprocessedImages.size() > 0)
            {
                imageToProcess = unprocessedImages.back();
                unprocessedImages.pop_back();
            }
        }
        if(!imageToProcess.empty())
        {
            // We have an image to process so sleep to simulate processing
            this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(SIM_PROCESSING_TIME_MS));
            count++;
            cout << "Processed " << count << endl;
        }
        else if(!runThread) //The image loading thread is done and there are no more images to process
            break;

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
}

// Simulates the image capture thread.
// 'Captures' images then pushes them onto unprocessedImages which the image processing thread then reads from.
int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, intHandler);

    // Start thread to process images
    auto imageProcessingThread = std::thread(image_processing_thread);

    // Load 300 images into memory
    for (int count = 0; count < 300; count++)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
        auto img = GetImage();
        lock_guard<mutex> lk(unprocessedImageMutex);
        unprocessedImages.push_back(img);
    }

    // Allow processing thread to exit when it has finished
    runThread = 0;
    cout << "All images loaded in" << endl;
    imageProcessingThread.join();
    cout << "All images processed" << endl;

    while (keepRunning) {}
    return 1;
}
```

There is a bit of code so the program can be exited with a SIGINT. This code is not a part of my larger application

**Attempted fixes**

- Calling `unprocessedImages.reserve(1000)` at the top of main.
- Replacing `unprocessedImages` with a `std::array` and an index.
- Replacing `unprocessedImages` with a c array and an index.
- Using `copyTo` to move the Mats in an out of `unprocessedImages`.
- All of the above while wrapping `Mat` in `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` (e.g. `vector<unique_ptr<Mat>> unprocessedImages;`).

None of these attempts had any affect on the characteristics of the memory leak.

**Question**

What is causing the memory leak in my program? How are you meant to pass ownership of OpenCV Mats between different threads?

Thanks, James

Edit: Added an additional attempted fix.

Edit 2: Running with Valgrind results in the above code NOT leaking. This is backed up by Valgrind's report which states that all blocks were reachable when the program ended. From the programs print outs it is clear that running it in valgrind made it a single threaded application as the print statements inside the two threads are perfectly interleaved.

Edit 3: I modified `main` like below. The result was that the peak and minimum memory usage on every iteration of the outer loop was the same. On this particular run the minimum memory usage was 374MB.

```
int main() {    
    signal(SIGINT, intHandler);

while(keepRunning)
{
runThread = 1;
    // Start thread to process images
    auto imageProcessingThread = std::thread(image_processing_thread);

    /* ... */

    cout << "All images processed" << endl;
}

    while (keepRunning) {}
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: what's the size of unprocessedImages during processing when you observe the menory leak?

Comment: Your `unprocessedImages` array does not really belong to either of the threads, so passing ownership should not even enter into the picture, I think. Interesting question. Could it have something to do with `cv::Mat` 's interesting model of memory management?

Comment: @Micka I am observing the memory leak by checking the memory usage after all 300 images have been processed and at that time the size of `unprocessedImages` is 0.

Comment: I don't see any obvious leaks there, none of those attempted workarounds should be necessary. Did you try running it with Valgrind's memcheck or some similar tool?

Comment: @Dan Running with Valgrind results in the above code NOT leaking. This is backed up by Valgrind's report which states that all blocks were reachable when the program ended.

Comment: OK. What will happen if you put most of the body of `main` into a loop (starting with the first `auto` and ending with the `while`) and run that for a few iterations -- will the memory usage keep growing further?

Comment: @Dan Adding a while loop around the majority of main did not result in the memory leak compounding.

Comment: TBH, I'd say there's no leak, since if there was one, I'd expect the additional iterations to keep grabbing more memory (memory that's leaked is unusable). Perhaps you have misinterpreted some measurements?